# How can show the dropdown list using angularjs 1.69 and bootstrap 3.37

Tags: html, angularjs

I used the classic second dropdown from bootstrap but is not loading correctly, all the time is loading with the menu opened . Also on I do a click on request is going to the home page.

Requests

Leaving Permission

Vacation

Delegation

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method, using ng-option:

```
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="item for item in names">
<option></option>
</select>
```